# Why isn't plus_assoc rewriting correctly?

Tags: proof-techniques, coq

First I have `plus_assoc` ready.

```
Theorem plus_assoc : forall n m p : nat,
  n + (m + p) = (n + m) + p.
```

for simplicity we omit the proof of `plus_assoc`.

now I want to prove `plus_swap`:

```
Theorem plus_swap : forall n m p : nat,
  n + (m + p) = m + (n + p).
Proof. intros n m p. rewrite -> plus_assoc. ...
```

the equation was rewritten into `n + m + p = m + ( n + p )`,  rather than the expected `(n + m) + p = m + (n + p)`. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rewriting correctly. Coq doesn't print redundant parentheses. The `+` operator is left-associative, so `n + m + p` is a valid way of writing the term `(n + m) + p`, and Coq prints it without the parentheses.

```
Coq < Check (n + m) + p.
n + m + p
     : nat
```

Just to be clear, `n + m +p` and `(n + m) + p` are exactly the same term, not just terms that are equal. They're different ways to use notations to write `Nat.add (Nat.add n m)`.

```
Theorem plus_swap : forall n m p : nat,
  n + (m + p) = m + (n + p).
Proof.
  intros n m p.
  Unset Printing Notations.
  Show. (* Now the goal is shown as: eq (Nat.add n (Nat.add m p)) (Nat.add m (Nat.add n p)) *)
  rewrite -> plus_assoc. (* Now the goal is: eq (Nat.add (Nat.add n m) p) (Nat.add m (Nat.add n p)) *)
```